# What is the need of term 'closed circuit'?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, terminology, electrical-resistance, electronics

If a circuit is a closed path in which charges can flow then why do we have the term closed circuit? Doesn't the definition mean that a circuit is always closed.

Comment: Circuit is just the layout which can either be open or close.

Comment: So what is essential for any layout of circuit elements to be called a circuit

Comment: A layout which would conduct electricity when closed.

Comment: Wait wouldn't that mean a wire a bulb and a cell placed at a distance from each other would be a circuit. Because if closed they conduct electricity

Comment: Circuit is an arrangement of different electrical components, like a cell or bulb, which would conduct electricity when 'closed'. Dont bring distance into the picture. It's not like an arrangement would be called a circuit if the components are within 1 mile from each other. Circuit is just an arrangement.

Comment: If a car is a machine that gets you from place to place why do we need the terms "working car" and "broken car"?  Same with circuits. Sometimes somebody thinks they made a circuit but it isn't actually a circuit because it's not fully connected. So we have the term "closed circuit" to mean a circuit that's actually a circuit and not broken.

Comment: @ThePhoton so ultimately how do you define a circuit. Thanks

Comment: @user194517, in physics, a closed path around which current can flow. In real life: A bunch of components connected together to perform some function. For example, a logic gate IC is called an "integrated *circuit*" even though there's no closed path formed until you hook it up to a power supply.

Answer (score 1):

> why do we have the term closed circuit?

I believe this is a historical use that came about because of switches.

Definitionally, an open circuit is one that is not complete, and a closed circuit is one that is electrically complete. This is not unique to electricity, I've seen some variation on these theme in other places like water flow and even money. And thus your confusion, because it would seem that any circuit is, by definition, closed.

But electrical circuits often include switches. Switches used to be little bars of metal with a pivot at one end and a clasp at the other. It moves like a door seen from above. If you raise the bar the current stops, a motion that is like opening a door. So when the switch is open, you have an open circuit. The term is more like a verb than an adjective in this case; an open circuit is what you get from the action of opening the switch.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put when an circuit is "closed" it is not leaking in electricity (electric charges) or the wires are connected and as no electricity is allowed to leave the circuit it is called a "Closed Circuit" and the vice-versa goes for "Open Circuit".

Your welcome.